# JSON,parse fails in Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm running Karma 12.19 and using Jasmine to do unit tests. The only failing test fails at JSON.parse function.

Trace:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token d
    at Object.parse (native)
    at /var/html/components/src/controllers/MainCtrl.js:9:8129
    at /var/html/libs/angular/angular.min.js:72:199
    at J (/var/html/libs/angular/angular.min.js:99:469)
    at J (/var/html/libs/angular/angular.min.js:99:469)
    at /var/html/libs/angular/angular.min.js:101:126
    at k.$eval (/var/html/libs/angular/angular.min.js:111:353)
    at k.$digest (/var/html/libs/angular/angular.min.js:108:419)
    at k.$apply (/var/html/libs/angular/angular.min.js:112:173)
    at h (/var/html/libs/angular/angular.min.js:72:454)
```

Code fails at this line:

```
for (var i = 0; i < templates.length; i++) {
    templates[i].data = JSON.parse(templates[i].data); // here
}
```

The code runs as expected and without errors in production, but jasmine and/or Karma aren't handling it.

Test data:

`var templates = [{data: "data", name: "name"}];`

Any suggestions?

Comment: `templates[i].data` contains invalid JSON. Could you show what`s in it?

Comment: In the test:
var templates = [{data: "data", name: "name"}];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to parse "data" to a JSON, which is not valid JSON.
You can parse the whole templates to JSON but then you would have to wrap its declaration in sinqle quotes to make it a string:

```
var templates = '[{data: "data", name: "name"}]';
```

Or if you want to keep what you are doing put a valid JSON to the data property:

```
var templates = [{data: '{x: "something"}', name: "name"}];
```

Comment: The whole object gets parsed, templates[0] that's to say. Both return an error.

Comment: Well, in the code I see JSON.parse(templates[i].data); which means that in fact it is JSON.parse("data") which obviously isn't correct. If you parse JSON anywhere else in the code, please provide it.

Comment: @DavidBohunek, isn't both key and value to be double quoted? In your example, 'x' is not quoted which will throw error while parsing.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a working javascript object (which is not necessarily a valid JSON object) that you would like to parse for testing, you can use something like:

```
var templates = [JSON.stringify({data: "data", name: "name"})];
```

This should work for you

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u. I can't get a better stack trace since neither source mapping or browserify seem to want to play ball. But this still returns an error like the one above.

Comment: u means it's trying to parse undefined.